# Android Terminal and Log Dumping

Tags: android, logging, terminal, android-sdcard

I am trying to send terminal commands programmaticly from an android activity.  At the moment I'm using something like the following:

```
Process process = null;
    DataOutputStream os = null;
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
    os.writeBytes("./data/program1\n");
    os.writeBytes("./data/program2\n");
    os.writeBytes("exit\n");
    os.flush();
```

However, my program1 is failing to run successfully and I believe it is due to inadequate user permissions.  Now for my question:

Does anyone know how I can dump the terminal to a file and save it on the phone or sdcard?  The program is tying into the terminal to feed it commands, I want to know a way to open a connection the otherway and access the (what is normally visual on a terminal screen) output.

Answer (score 0):

See the sources for the Terminal application, as that is bidirectional.

Sadly, running shell commands or launching native processes is not an officially supported part of android, so no future stability is guaranteed.